# Vscode extension suggestion not working on some folders

Tags: python, html, css, django, visual-studio-code

When I tried to create a HTML file inside my django project folder (appfolder/templat/test/page.html) it's not suggesting any tags when I type.
But same time it's working on html files that are outside those folder it works perfectly

Now I'm creating html file outside and paste it to that folder . How can I solve this ??

Comment: what's the language mode for the editor tab for that file? (check the language mode indicator in the bottom right corner)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Any updates here?